# Grouping with previous data

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, cumulative-sum

There is a table of users

```
ID | DATE_CR
```

Group by month

```
SELECT TO_CHAR (operation_time, 'YYYY-MM'), count(ID) from users GROUP BY TO_CHAR (operation_time, 'YYYY-MM')
```

I get the number of months registered

```
January 10
February 3
March 5
```

But at the output, I want to get

```
January 10
February 13
March 18
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to place your current query into a CTE and then use a correlated subquery to compute the running total.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        TO_CHAR (operation_time, 'YYYY-MM') AS mdate,
        COUNT(ID) AS total
    FROM users
    GROUP BY TO_CHAR (operation_time, 'YYYY-MM')
)
SELECT t1.mdate,
       (SELECT SUM(t2.total) FROM cte t2
        WHERE t2.mdate <= t1.mdate) AS running_total
FROM cte t1
```

Another approach, which might perform better, would be to use window functions.  Someone like @GordonLinoff will tell you about that.

Comment: Isn't this a window function ?